# Magento, using ACL for frontend. Possible?

Tags: magento, acl, frontend

Is it possible to use Magentos ACL for frontend?
All examples found are backend specific.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm working on a heavily modified Magento project, and have different roles for frontend users. So, I'm just wondering if Magentos ACL can be used there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is possible. You can turn Magento inside-out hacking the core. The question is the price. ACL is built for back-end users and back-end events. So making it work with both back-end and front-end users/events .. you know, the short answer is "No".

Comment: Yep, that was also my own conclusion. I ended up making my own using Zend_Acl. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this module "dized/module-front-acl" from my repository could be helpful: https://github.com/di-zed/m2-front-acl

ACL System for the Front Part of the Magento 2 project.
The module that will allow you to take full advantage of the front-end ACL capabilities in the modules you develop.

Key Features:

- Ability to create your own roles and permissions via XML file.
- Ability to set default permissions for each of the roles.
- Ability to set the necessary roles and permissions for each customer in - the admin panel.
- Ability to automatically set the default role and permissions for a newly created customer (using a plugin).
- Ability to easily use this functionality for controllers/actions and blocks.

Comment: I have disclosed affiliation for you this time. Please do the same for your posts on the Magento Stack Exchange as this is a requirement on the Stack Exchange platform.